# Spring controller does not load view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I calling a controller via button click using ajax. I want it to load hello.html page but I want spring to do it not ajax.

What happens after I click the button is nothing but I'm sure the controller is being hit.

Here is the controller I'm calling via button click using ajax.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/submitName", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String submitName(@RequestParam String name, Model model) {
        System.out.println(name);
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "hello";
    }
```

Here is the ajax call.

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/submitName',
        data: {name: $('#name').val()}
    });
});
```

Funny thing is in the chrome network tab it shows the page that I'm expecting. Here is a snippet.

[image]

Comment: did you try with   `dataType: 'html'` on your ajax call?

Comment: If you don't want to use ajax to get the content, why bother with $.ajax.  Why don't just load the page directly $('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
    $("#your_target").load('/submitName?name=' + $('#name').val();)
})

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is ok here, except you didn't mention how you want to show your page or where. You have to declare a container where your html returned from controller would appear, like under a `div id` or something like that.
So, just in your current html page, declare a new tag, may be `<div id="current-page-id"></div>`

Now, append the hello.html page to your current page using jquery:

```
$("#current-page-id").html(responseData);
```

So, basically, do this:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/submitName',
            data: {name: $('#name').val()},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (responseData) {
                $('#current-page-id').html(responseData);
              
            },
        });
```

Or, simply, load the page as separate html page, not via ajax.

### Update:

instead of using ajax-as you asked for in comment section, do this as follows:

```
function getHtmlPage(String name)
{
   location.href = 'submitName/' + name;
}
```

Now call your method on button click:

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
   var name=$('#name').val();
   getHtmlPage(name);
});
```

Comment: How do I load it to a separate html page without the parameter 'name' appearing in the url?

Comment: you either have to send your `name` via `url-parameter` or by `pathvariable`. which one do your prefer?
Another thing to be cleared: If you want  to submit data, your method should be `POST`, but if you want to fetch by name or id or by something, `GET` is ok then which is standard way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX Calling just send the request to the server (controller) and received a response,

By default, It's dos not responsibility for reloading the page.

In this why when you click the button it hit the server-side but stay on the same page.

Simple there is two way you can load your new page ( hello.html )

1| With AJAX calling:

On the button click method, you have to explicitly load the page (Best practice in Ajax Success block)

adding this window load metbod:
          window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/hello.html";

```
 Like: 

 $('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/submitName',
    data: {name: $('#name').val()}
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/hello.html";
  });
 });
```

2|  Direct Http Call on the Button

HTML

```
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" href="http://localhost:8080/hello" role="button">Hello Page</a>
```

JSP:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hello" role="button">Hello page</a>
```

Thymeleaf

```
<a class="btn btn-xs" th:href="@{/hello})}">Hello Page </a>
```